# SELECT all strings with numbers

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I have a long list in a varchar column (SQL Server) with data like:

```
Hello World
Hello World 2
1 Hello World
Again this is Hello World
Hello 100 World
500
```

I want to SELECT all the strings which contain a number in it. For example, in above, I need:

```
Hello World 2
1 Hello World
Hello 100 World
500
```

How can I do it with SELECT SQL?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM tableName
WHERE columnName like '%[0-9]%'
```

Comment: koi nai , khush raho bhai

Comment: @mmhasannn Out of curiosity, what does that mean?

Comment: @wewesthemenace " .. nevermind , be happy brother .. "

Answer (score 3):

You can Use Regular Expression `[0-9]` which will select all rows with numbers between 0 and 9

```
Declare @tab as table(data varchar(50))
 insert into @tab values
 ('Hello World 3'),('Hello World')
 select * from @tab where data like '%[0-9]%'
```

**OUTPUT**

Hello World 3

Comment: A word of advice - if you are showing sample data, include a negative case as well to show that the logic rejects invalid data in addition to allowing valid data :)